# Etymology of "far out"

Tags: etymology, slang

Where does the expression *far out* come from?

As in:

> I had to phone someone so I picked on you /
>   Hey, that's *far out* so you heard him too! /
>   Switch on the TV we may pick him up on channel two

(This is a lyric from "Starman" by David Bowie)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### OED

The *Oxford English Dictionary* defines *far out* as:

> Of jazz: of the latest or most progressive kind. More generally, avant-garde, far-fetched; excellent, splendid. orig. *U.S.*

Their first quotation is an [8th November 1954](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,857658,00.html) *Time Magazine* article entitled "Far-Out Words for Cats":

> Jazz lingo becomes obsolescent almost as fast as it reaches the public ear.‥ A daring performance was ‘hot’, then ‘cool’, and now is ‘far out’.

---

### 1940s

We can see this term beginning to emerge in Simon Michael Bessie's [1938](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=LrvTT9r5GvOO4gS7uJybAw&id=tJo4AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22far%20out%22%20AND%20jazz&q=%22far%20out%22#search_anchor) book *Jazz Journalism: The Story of the Tabloid Newspapers*:

> The third class, divertingly **far out on the lunatic fringe**, embraces such journalistic peep-shows as Bernarr Macfadden's *New York Evening Graphic*.

Whilst the book is about tabloid papers and not jazz, it shows "far out" being applied to something novel and possibly avant-garde.

Here's *Esquire's [1946](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=_7zTT8LcOeio4gTpwtijAw&id=-xk5AAAAIAAJ&dq=%22far%20out%22%20AND%20jazz&q=%22far%20out%22#search_anchor) Jazz Book* applying it to jazz of the most progressive kind:

> Much of its drive came from two other jazzmen on this list: drummer Davey Tough and bassist Chubby Jackson. Both are incomparable musicians; both have contributed mightily to that spark and zest which are so characteristic of Woody's band and which take it **far out of the realm** of the typical swing band.

Here's another snippet, from a [1947](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=_7zTT8LcOeio4gTpwtijAw&id=D5o4AQAAIAAJ&dq=%22far%20out%22%20AND%20jazz&q=%22far%20out%22%20#search_anchor) *The Jazz Record*:

> George [Lugg] sat staring miserably at the floor, and when the trombone solos came along he made impatient gestures and said: "That wasn't what I wanted to do at all." But in some of those ensemble passages, banging away behind Goodwin's trumpet and Scott's clarinet, with a good rhythm section pushing, he began to grin and nod his head. "That's it!" he'd say. 'That's good." He was so impersonal, **so far out of himself**, a musician listening to music and judging it by what he heard.

And from the next page:

> Shuffle up that "Chain Gang" thing. Hear this cat blowing blue in the lost reaches of the world's last swamp. Go with this Yank into the eternal night, so **far out of the world** that nothing remains but the half-remembered crying of a horn. Born of slavery's misery comes jazz, bringing the gap from cat to cat with a blue bridge.

These may not be the exact use of the phrase, but give an indication of how it came around.

---

### 1954

It appears to have used as a set term in a publication of the South Dakota State University sometime in [1954](http://books.google.fi/books?ei=IsLTT9eWM6mO4gSD5p2QAw&id=a95MAAAAYAAJ&dq=%22far%20out%22%20AND%20jazz&q=%22far%20out%22#search_anchor):

> ... Ella Fitzgerald and hundreds of other "cats." To put expression for our word "darin;[?] into jazz terms, **the jazz today is "far-out"**.

*Billboard* of [24 April 1954](http://books.google.fi/books?id=Ph8EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA42&dq=%22far%20out%22%20AND%20jazz&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IsLTT9eWM6mO4gSD5p2QAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22far%20out%22%20&f=false) reviews Les Elgart Orchestra's song "East is East":

> A pretty instrumental with an exotic Oriental flavor. The virtuosity of Elgart's intrumentalists makes for easy listening, but there is a solid beat here for dancing. A little on the modern side, but not too **far out**.

*Billboard* of [26 June 1954](http://books.google.fi/books?id=oB4EAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA32&dq=%22far%20out%22%20AND%20jazz&hl=en&sa=X&ei=IsLTT9eWM6mO4gSD5p2QAw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=%22far%20out%22%20&f=false) reviews Serena Shaw's "St. Louis Blues":

> Here is the perennial as you might expect Yma Sumac to sing it. Miss Shaw, aided by exotic sounds from drums, organ and echo chamber, soars up and zooms down a two-octave range at a dizzying pace, working up to a frantic pitch at the end. **It's pretty far out**, but deejays might find it unusual programming.

The same [November 8, 1954](http://www.time.com/time/magazine/article/0,9171,857657,00.html) *Time Magazine* cited by the *OED* had another article that used:

> Says Jazz Promoter Norman Granz, who does not always understand [David] Brubeck's **"far-out" music**: "He's way out on Cloud 7."

Answer (score 4):

http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=far+out

> **far out** 
>       also far-out, 1887, "remote, distant;" from far + out. Slang sense
>   of "excellent, wonderful," is from
>   1954, originally in [jazz talk](http://www.allaboutjazz.com/php/article.php?id=1404).

as in Beyond Great :)

Comment: So... what exactly is "jazz talk" then?

Comment: @Nico - see update link

Answer (score 0):

Robert Frost and Aldous Huxley wrote "Neither Far Out or In Deep" in 1939.
I think that might be a better starting place

Comment: Here's the [full text](http://studentacademichelp.blogspot.com/2009/10/robert-frost-critical-analysis-of.html) of Frost's poem. / I don't think it's the same as the jazz slang.

Answer (score -2):

The words *far* and *out* have been around forever but John Denver made the phrase "far out" popular.

Comment: Do you have a source to support this claim?